# Cypress : choose username and environment from a list

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have the following code and idea and I want to make it functional so that I can log in to the test with the function as cy.login (live, username):

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (env,username) => {
        env  = Cypress.env('staging')
        env = Cypress.env('live')
        username = Cypress.username('username1')
        username = Cypress.username('username2')
    cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type('username')
    cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type('password1')
    cy.contains('Login').click()
})
```

Certainly my code is not a functional one, but I want to understand the idea and how to write it in order to be able to use a variable several times.

And in cypress.json

```
    {"env": {
        "staging": "https://staginglink",
        "live": "https://livelink"
      }}

  {"username": {
        "username1": "username": "username1", "password" : "password1" ,
        "username2": "username": "username2", "password" : "password2" ,
      }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with a fix to cypress.json

```html
{
  "env": {
    "links": {
      "staging": "https://staginglink",
      "live": "https://livelink"
    }
    "users": {
      "user1": {"username": "username1", "password" : "password1"},
      "user2": {"username": "username2", "password" : "password2"},
    }
}
```

Calling with string parameters:

```js
cy.login('live', 'user2')
```

**Command:**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (requiredEnv, requiredUser) => {

  const links = Cypress.env('links');  // links section above
  const link = links[requiredEnv];     // if passed "live" or "staging", gives the
                                       // correct property of links section
  cy.visit(link)

  const users = Cypress.env('users');    // users section above
  const user = users[requiredUser];          

  const username = user.username;  // "user1" -> gives "username1"
                                   // "user2" -> gives "username2"

  const password = user.password;  // "user1" -> gives "password1"
                                   // "user2" -> gives "password2"

  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type(username)  // don't put quotes around variable
  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type(password)  // don't put quotes around variable
  cy.contains('Login').click()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Cypress.json` you can arrange your data like this:

```js
{
   "env":{
      "staging":"https://staginglink",
      "live":"https://livelink"
   },
   "users":{
      "user1":{
         "username":"username1",
         "password":"password1"
      },
      "user2":{
         "username":"username2",
         "password":"password2"
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your test you can access the data like:

```js
Cypress.config('users').user1.username. //gets username1
Cypress.env('staging'). //gets staging link
```

Your custom command will look like:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (user, env) => {
  cy.visit(env)
  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type(user.username)
  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type(user.password)
  cy.contains('Login').click()
})
```

From your test you can write:

```js
cy.login(Cypress.config('users').user1, Cypress.env('staging'))
cy.login(Cypress.config('users').user2, Cypress.env('live'))
```